# Match pattern and insert this pattern after every character until end of line

Tags: shell, perl, sed

I've got a line with an identifier, then a pattern (in my case, a semicolon) and then a list of numbers:

```
echo "sp16;111111111111111111111111111111211"
```

I'd like to insert a semicolon between all numbers as in (desired output):

```
echo "sp16;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;2;1;1"
```

So far, I found how to insert a semicolon between all characters using `sed`:

```
sed 's/.\{1\}/&;/g'
```

But, then it also inserts semicolons before matching the first semicolon and also it adds a semicolon ad the end of the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a `Perl`'s one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/^([^;]+;)([0-9]+)/$1 . join ";", split "", $2/e' file
```

```
sp16;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;2;1;1
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string anchor |
| `(` | group and capture to \1: |
| `[^;]+` | any character except: `;` (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `;` | ; |
| `)` | end of \1 |
| `(` | group and capture to \2: |
| `[0-9]+` | any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \2 |

##### Perl's code explanations

| Operator | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `$1` | captured group 1 like \1 in sed |
| `.` | concatenation |
| `join ";",` | join with the character ';' the following list... |
| `split "", $2` | split captured group $2 or \2 in a list of digits |
| `e` | modifier that allow Perl's code/expression in the right part of substitution s/// |

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed`:

```
echo "sp16;111111111111111111111111111111211" \
  | sed -E ':a; s/(;[^;])([^;]+)$/\1;\2/; ta'
```

Output:

```
sp16;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;2;1;1
```

See: `man sed` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ echo "sp16;111111111111111111111111111111211" |
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {gsub(/./,FS"&",$2); sub(FS,"")} 1'
sp16;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;2;1;1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `sed` command that will work for any `sed` version:

```bash
sed -E -e :a -e 's/([0-9])([0-9]+)$/\1;\2/; ta' file

sp16;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;2;1;1
```

Here is a suggested `awk` solution:

```bash
awk -F';' -v OFS= '{gsub(/./, FS "&", $2)} 1' file

sp16;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;2;1;1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/;/\n/;h;s/\B/;/g;H;x;s/\n.*\n/;/' file
```

Divide and conquer.

Replace the first delimiter `;`, by a newline and make a copy.

Insert a `;` between each in-word character.

Append the result to original copy.

Replace everything between the two introduced newlines by `;`.

---

If the first identifier is always 4 characters:

```
sed 's/./;&/7g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "sp16;111111111111111111111111111111211" |
```

---

```
mawk 'gsub(".", ";&", $NF)' OFS= FS=';'
```

---

```
sp16;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;2;1;1
```